# change process priority in android

Tags: android, process

How to change process priority in Android? I have found process description and description of it's priorities in android docs

[process and thread description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html)

[process priorities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND)

but I have found nothing on changing process priority by some method.

ps: I need this to test only some feature of application which is connected with process priority and it won't be used in program.

The only way I see is to try to change the priority via **importance** field, but it's a bad idea I guess.

Comment: I think you are correct, you can set priority on threads only and it is not guaranteed that your set priority will be always applied. Android OS determines based on need.

Comment: Why do you think using the importance field is a bad idea? It seems that setting the importance field to which ever constant is most relevant will change the priority of the process. Also if you would like to more fine tune the past the constant levels given, you can use the Iru field.

Comment: I think that it's a bad idea because changing the value of a field which was set by system is not the good practice

Comment: I don't know if this is general, but you might find "Show CPU usage" under the developer options in settings. This will not tell you what process priority you have, but it will give you an idea of how processes behave in relation to one another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to change process priority in Android?

You can't, except perhaps on a rooted device, and then only temporarily. Process priority is managed by the OS. If your app is in the foreground, it will run with foreground priority. If your app is not in the foreground, it will not run with foreground priority.

> I need this to test only some feature of application which is connected with process priority and it won't be used in program.

Then test with a process that is in the foreground versus one that is not.

> The only way I see is to try to change the priority via importance field, but it's a bad idea I guess.

Changing that number is unlikely to have an effect. `RunningAppProcessInfo` is an output structure, not a means by which to change anything reported via that structure.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @GlennMaynard: Edited.

Answer (score 1):

*setpriority()* and *getPriority()* in the native code exists, so may be we can set the priority from the native code. But, I am not sure whether it takes effect by the os or neglects it.

Answer (score 1):

This only works with a rooted device:

Use a terminal, become root by inputting

```
    su
```

then select the process-id from the output of top

```
    top -n 1 -m 10
```

look in the column PID and renice the process (in this example PID 1825 to priority 0) you want to by

```
    renice 0 1825
```

That's all. 
Keep in mind, that this change will be overwritten by the OperatingSystem, after some time, when OS thinks it was necessary to give the process more priority.