# Android - Start a new activity while the application is in the background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

The first activity of my application is a splash screen, where some animation is displayed while some loading occurs in a background thread using **AsyncTask**.
Once the loading in the background is done, I want to start a new activity. What is the correct way to do that ?

1. Start a new activity directly from the **onPostExecute** method of the **AsyncTask** class.
2. Check if the current activity is displayed before starting the new activity :

   - If the current activity is display, start the new activity.
   - If the current activity is **NOT** display, use a flag (boolean) and check the flag during the **onResume** method in order to start the new activity there.

### My main concern is :

If my application went to the background (due to an incoming phone call, a home key press, ...) and the background thread (AsyncTask) finished executing, and a new activity is started from the **onPostExecute** method while my application **is still in the background** : What happens ?

- Will the new activity start directly as soon as my application is visible again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience i am answering your question

**Question1**

If you using AsyncTask you have to start new activity in `OnPostExecute()`. In my experience this is the correct way of doing it.

**Question2**

When ever your press the home key or receiving phone call. Your activity will go in to background until you exit the app by pressing back button(at that time your app is exited). So when you come back to your app your new activity will be visible if background process get finished. Otherwise you will see the start splash screen.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I tried starting the new activity inside **onPostExecute** and it works perfectly. However it is not the behavior I am looking for, nonetheless this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar situation: my application went to background and after some time the app started an intent displaying another activity. However, the app's behavior now depends on the os that it's running:

- **on pre 4.4 devices** the app silently opens the new activity and remains in background. When the user resumes the application, he is prompted with the second activity already.
- **on 4.4 devices** (tested on 4.4.2 and 4.4.4) the app opens the second activity, but after 3-4 seconds, the app pops to foreground, interrumping the user.

Hope it helps anybody. I'm still looking solutions for the second case in order to prevent the app from popping to foreground.

Comment: Thank you for your answer regarding the devices running android 4.4 , I didn't know that. Maybe you can check if your app is on the foreground before starting a new activity ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is dependent upon the OS of android.  It has defined some built in priority model for each of the components.

Look at the answer given by commonsware.

[change process priority in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281543/change-process-priority-in-android)

this gives brief idea about components priority.